# Why does python import module imports when importing *

Tags: python, import, python-import

Let's say I have a file where I'm importing some packages:

```
# myfile.py
import os
import re
import pathlib

def func(x, y):
    print(x, y)
```

If I go into another file and enter

```
from myfile import *
```

Not only does it import `func`, but it also imports `os`, `re`, and `pathlib`,

but I **DO NOT** want those modules to be imported when I do `import *`.

Why is it importing the other packages I'm importing and how do you avoid this?

Comment: Congrats, you've found one of the many reasons not to use `import *`. Stop using it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone explain \_\_all\_\_ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)

Comment: `Why is it importing the other packages I'm importing and how do you avoid this?` If everything(hence `import *`) on your package works without those libraries, why are you importing them?

Comment: If those aren't necessary to import, then why are they in the module you're importing? If you're wanting to import things from your module that rely on those, why would you want to not import the modules that those rely on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The reason

Because `import` imports every *name* in the namespace. If something has a name inside the module, then it's valid to be exported.

#### How to avoid

First of all, you should almost never be using `import *`. It's almost always clearer code to either import the specific methods/variables you're trying to use (`from module import func`), or to import the whole module and access methods/variables via dot notation (`import module; ...; module.func()`).

That said,  if you must use `import * from module`, there are a few ways to prevent certain names from being exported from `module`:

1. Names starting with `_` will not be imported by `import * from ...`. They can still be imported directly (i.e. `from module import _name`), but not automatically. This means you can rename your imports so that they don't get exported, e.g. `import os as _os`. However, this also means that your entire code in that module has to refer to the `_os` instead of `os`, so you may have to modify lots of code.
2. If a module contains the name `__all__: List[str]`, then `import *` will export only the names contained in that list. In your example, add the line `__all__ = ['func']` to your `myfile.py`, and then `import *` will only import `func`. [See also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python).

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. If I just import myfile I didn't want to import the other things as well (like re, os, or pathlib in this case)

Answer (score 1):

```
from myfile import func
```

Here is the fix :)

When you `import *`, you import everything from. Which includes what yu imported in the file your source.

Answer (score 0):

It has actually been discussed on [Medium](https://s16h.medium.com/importing-star-in-python-88fe9e8bd4d2), but for simplification, I will answer it myself.

`from <module/package> import *` is a way to import all the names we can get in that specific module/package. Usually, everyone doesn't actually use `import *` for this reason, and rather sticked with `import <module>`.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `import` essentially just runs the file you point it to import (it's not quite that but close enough). So if you import a module it will also import all the things the module imports. If you want to import only specific functions within the module, try:

`from myfile import func`

...which would import only `myfile.func()` instead of the other things as well.